# calculate age with year month and day on specific date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to calculate age of person, where result calculates Years, Months & Days, and combines these three to get a text that looks like, for an example `31 Years, 7 Months, and 16 Days`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The DATEDIF functions solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

- *In some of the older versions unit
  "MD" returns wrong value, but now
  the bug has been fixed.*
- *Below show formula works properly with
  version 2010 and higher.*

[image]

- If you want to use Current date then use this formula in cell T2:

  ```
  =DATEDIF(R2,TODAY(),"Y")&" Years "&DATEDIF(R2,TODAY(),"YM")&" Months "&DATEDIF(R2,TODAY(),"MD")&" Days"
  ```
- In case you want to use any date other than Current date then use this is cell T4:

  ```
  =DATEDIF(R2,S2,"Y")&" Years "&DATEDIF(R2,S2,"YM")&" Months "&DATEDIF(R2,S2,"MD")&" Days"
  ```

---

**N.B.**

- In some cases the formula returns ZERO for either Year, Month or Days, you can avoid this by using IF with DATEDIF.

---

[image]

- I've used the standard DATEDIF in cell T2, returns ZERO for Month, to avoid this you can use formula wrapped with IF, as I've used in cell T4.

  ```
  =IF(DATEDIF(R2,S2,"y")=0,"",DATEDIF(R2,S2,"y")&" years, ")&IF(DATEDIF(R2,S2,"ym")=0,"",DATEDIF(R2,S2,"ym")&" months, ")&IF(DATEDIF(R2,S2,"md")=0,"",DATEDIF(R2,S2,"md")&" days")
  ```
- In case you don't like using the DATEDIF function then, you may use this one, is in cell T6.

  ```
   =INT((S2-R2)/365.25)&" Years, " & INT(MOD((S2-R2)/365.25,1)*12)&" Months, " & INT(MOD((S2-R2)/30.4375,1)*30.4375)&" Days"
  ```

*You may adjust cell reference in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I suggest adding a caveat to your response that the `DATEDIF` function was broken in Excel 2007.  It seems to be fixed now, but I don't know when that fix was made.  In that version, the `MD` argument would return wildly incorrect results for certain inputs. See [MD Days function returns wrong value](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/md-days-function-returns-wrong-value/9fdd6b3f-e2aa-4289-b16c-88c2c5f6cd8b?auth=1)

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Keshab,, glad to help you keep asking ☺

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,, nice suggestion,, now I've updated my post with description all about unit MD, also suggested few alternate formula. ☺